# I want to move an image on screen while holding down a key. How can i get it?

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I made this thinking that it would works, but it doesn't XD
it only moves the image one time per click
Help me please

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == QUIT:
        pygame.quit()
        sys.exit()

    while event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        right == K_RIGHT
        left == K_LEFT
        if right == 1
            posX += velocidad
        elif lef == 1:
            posX -= velocidad
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to used `pygame.key.get_pressed()`  as follows.

```
for event in pygame.event.get():   
    if event.type == QUIT:
        pygame.quit()
        sys.exit()

pressed_keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
if pressed_keys[K_RIGHT]:
    posX += velocidad
if pressed_keys[K_LEFT]:
    posX -= velocidad
```

event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN only catches when a key is first pressed down. 
If you want to use this you could switch some attribute like your_object.moving_right = True. Then use keyup to turn it off again.

Answer (score 0):

Overall, I think what you want is to check `event.key` with an if statement.

However there are multiple problems (both structural and syntactic) with your code. `event.type` doesn't change, so using `while` doesn't make sense (and this will run forever and make your program hang). I'm not sure what your intent is with the `== 1` comparisons, as K_RIGHT and K_LEFT are arbitrary constants for key code values. Not to mention that `right == K_RIGHT` is an expression that does nothing (did you mean `right = K_RIGHT`?) and you've got a clear typo with `lef`. I think the closest working code to the structure you've provided (assuming the other code not shown also works) would look something like this:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
  if event.type == QUIT:
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()

  if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
    right = K_RIGHT
    left = K_LEFT
    if event.key == right:
        posX += velocidad
    elif event.key == left:
        posX -= velocidad
```